# Glassfish 4 - remotely cannot access admin console when 'enable-secure-admin' is enabled

Tags: glassfish, payara

We are using Glassfish and cannot access admin console remotely when 'enable-secure-admin' is enabled using the default port 4848.

We are trying access over dev-vpn, but cannot do so when we use the subcommand 'enable-secure-admin' .  If it is disabled we can see the web-page but cannot login.

Is it something to do with 'http-redirect' ?

Comment: Do you access the admin using HTTPS or HTTP? Do you get any errors in the server.log file? It is not clear what is hapenning, try posting a screenshot too.

Comment: Yes , we are trying to access over HTTPS . There is no error on the server log , infact cant find any log when the 'enable-secure-admin' is enabled.

Comment: On the server when we try to 'curl' the admin console , it returns contents with status '200'

Comment: If you can access admin console using curl from local server, it is most probably due to the http redirect. Do you use Apache Http server? Have you configured the redirect also for SSL/HTTPS?