# Glassfish 4 - cannot log into Administration Console

Tags: java, glassfish, debian, raspberry-pi3

This will probably get flagged as a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37892580/glassfish-4-remotely-cannot-access-admin-console-when-enable-secure-admin-is), but it hasn't yet been answered and I don't have enough rep to ask them if they have found a solution.

So I have Glassfish4 setup on a Raspi on my LAN. I can see port 8080 just fine. However, when I go to the Admin port I see this.

[image: Admin Web page]

So I need to enable Secure Admin. Everything goes smooth until restart-domain.

```
pi@raspberrypi:/home/downloads/glassfish4/glassfish/bin $ sudo ./asadmin change-admin-password
    Enter admin user name [default: admin]>admin
    Enter the admin password>
    Enter the new admin password>
    Enter the new admin password again>
    Command change-admin-password executed successfully.

pi@raspberrypi:/home/downloads/glassfish4/glassfish/bin $ sudo ./asadmin enable-secure-admin
    Enter admin user name>  admin
    Enter admin password for user "admin">
    You must restart all running servers for the change in secure admin to take effect.
    Command enable-secure-admin executed successfully.
    
pi@raspberrypi:/home/downloads/glassfish4/glassfish/bin $ sudo ./asadmin restart-domain
    NCLS-ADMIN-00010
    NCLS-ADMIN-00010
    NCLS-ADMIN-00010
    NCLS-ADMIN-00010
    NCLS-ADMIN-00010
    NCLS-ADMIN-00010
    NCLS-ADMIN-00010
    NCLS-ADMIN-00010
    NCLS-ADMIN-00010
    NCLS-ADMIN-00010
    NCLS-ADMIN-00010
    NCLS-ADMIN-00010
    NCLS-ADMIN-00010
    NCLS-ADMIN-00010
    NCLS-ADMIN-00010
    NCLS-ADMIN-00010
    NCLS-ADMIN-00010
    NCLS-ADMIN-00010
    NCLS-ADMIN-00010
    ...
```

After that I cannot even check the Admin Log-in screen. So I check the logs and here is what is happening.

```
[2016-06-30T13:34:57.035-0500] [glassfish 4.0] [WARNING] [] [org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain] [tid: _ThreadID=33 _ThreadName=admin-listener(3)] [timeMillis: 1467311697035] [levelValue: 900] [[
Exception during FilterChain execution
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not generate dummy secret
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.checkThrown(Handshaker.java:1429)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.checkTaskThrown(SSLEngineImpl.java:535)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readNetRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:813)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:781)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:624)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ssl.SSLConnectionContext.unwrap(SSLConnectionContext.java:172)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ssl.SSLUtils.handshakeUnwrap(SSLUtils.java:268)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ssl.SSLBaseFilter.doHandshakeStep(SSLBaseFilter.java:596)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ssl.SSLBaseFilter.doHandshakeStep(SSLBaseFilter.java:545)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ssl.SSLBaseFilter.handleRead(SSLBaseFilter.java:266)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.portunif.PUFilter.handleRead(PUFilter.java:231)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not generate dummy secret
    at sun.security.ssl.RSAClientKeyExchange.<init>(RSAClientKeyExchange.java:152)
    at sun.security.ssl.ServerHandshaker.processMessage(ServerHandshaker.java:246)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:979)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:919)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:916)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$DelegatedTask.run(Handshaker.java:1369)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ssl.SSLUtils.executeDelegatedTask(SSLUtils.java:252)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ssl.SSLBaseFilter.doHandshakeStep(SSLBaseFilter.java:631)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Cannot find any provider supporting RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.java:540)
    at sun.security.ssl.JsseJce.getCipher(JsseJce.java:229)
    at sun.security.ssl.RSAClientKeyExchange.<init>(RSAClientKeyExchange.java:116)
    ... 31 more
]]
```

I going out on a limb and thinking it has to do with security-keys, but the constant looping of message in the shell makes me think otherwise.

Thanks for any help. I can provide more things if you think it will help.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of the question you referenced. I think it is more likely a configuration issue related to the JDK. The last message seems to suggest that there is something going wrong with the SSL handshake. The admin console is essentially a wrapper around the REST admin interface and does 2-way SSL with the server when secure admin is enabled. What is the output of `java -version`?

Comment: A workaround to this would be to access the admin console over an SSH tunnel to your Raspberry Pi. You can do this with PuTTY or on the command line with Linux. [[Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/PortForwarding)] | [[PuTTY](https://howto.ccs.neu.edu/howto/windows/ssh-port-tunneling-with-putty)]

Comment: @Mike java version "1.8.0_91"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.91-b14, mixed mode)

Comment: @Mike I already am connecting to my PI via SSH and deploying apps by using the asadmin commands. Its using jesse lite so there is no gui associated with PI's OS. I just wanted a faster deployment method, without having to write a script and editing it for each time I make a new app name that sort of thing.

Comment: This may happen if you could have improperly modified Network Config/Http 2/SSL settings incorrectly or when the keystores/trustores in domain/domain_name/config are modified in some way.

A good idea is to always make a backup of your config directory before you experiment on delicate settings

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem after clean install of glassfish-5.0-web-b16-07_30_2017  on Solaris 11.3 with JDK 1.8.0_60-b27. Was trying to update Solaris 11.3 jdk-8 package, but the answer from Oracle repository was "no updates available". But I knew that there was newer version of JDK. So after downloading the file jdk-8u144-solaris-x64.tar.gz and installing it everythig started to work :)